# VB.net VB Serializing JSON Property Name issue

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm having an issue with a JSON property name. It might be because I don't know what I'm doing. This is my 1st attempt at serializing JSON (with vb.net VB)

The result I'm looking for is this:

```
{
  "login": {
    "username": "XXX",
    "password": "pwxXXxx",
    "busId": "123456789",
    "busRole": "Third Party",
    "paymentTerms": "Prepaid"
  }
}
```

This is what I am getting:

```
[
    {
        "login": null,
        "username": "1234",
        "password": "pw123456",
        "busId": "12345",
        "busRole": "Third Party",
        "paymentTerms": "Prepaid"
    }
]
```

My issue is with the piece "login": {"   adds the colon and the term null. I'll post my code below
Any help would be appreciated.

-Thank You

```
Partial Class _Default
        Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim loads As New List(Of fgtload)()

        loads.Add(New fgtload() With {
        .username = "1234",
        .password = "pw123456",
        .busId = "12345",
        .busRole = "Third Party",
        .paymentTerms = "Prepaid"
         }
        )
        Dim strserialize As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loads)
        lblserial.Text = strserialize
End Sub


Public Class fgtload

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="login")>
    Public Property login As String

    Public Property username() As String
        Get
            Return m_username
        End Get
        Set
            m_username = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_username As String

    Public Property password() As String
        Get
            Return m_password
        End Get
        Set
            m_password = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_password As String

    Public Property busId() As String
        Get
            Return m_busId
        End Get
        Set
            m_busId = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_busId As String

    Public Property busRole() As String
        Get
            Return m_busRole
        End Get
        Set
            m_busRole = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_busRole As String


    Public Property paymentTerms() As String
        Get
            Return m_paymentTerms
        End Get
        Set
            m_paymentTerms = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_paymentTerms As String
End Class
```

Here's the entire JSON  output sampel Im trying to get.

```
   {
  "login": {
    "username": "XXX",
    "password": "pwxXXxx",
    "busId": "123456789",
    "busRole": "Third Party",
    "paymentTerms": "Prepaid"
  }
}
,
  "details": {
    "serviceClass": "STD",
    "typeQuery": "QUOTE",
    "pickupDate": "20200221",
    "productCode": "DFQ"
  },
  "originLocation": {
    "city": "Keyport",
    "state": "NJ",
    "postalCode": "07735",
    "country": "USA",
    "locationType": "COMM"
  },
  "destinationLocation": {
    "city": "Beverly Hills",
    "state": "CA",
    "postalCode": "90210",
    "country": "USA",
    "locationType": "COMM"
  },
  "listOfCommodities": {
    "commodity": [
      {
        "packageLength": 48,
        "packageWidth": 48,
        "packageHeight": 48,
        "weight": 1500,
        "handlingUnits": 1,
        "packageCode": "PLT"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How would I add another class to the wrapper.  For example

```
Public Class fgtDetails  ' 
    Public ServiceClass As String
    Public typeQuery As String
    Public pickupDate As Integer
    Public productCode As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to declare the login element as an empty string and is therefore serialized as null. From what you said you are trying to achieve, you want to declare login as an object that contains the Username, Password, BusID, BusRole, and PaymentTerms properties.

From what your looking for, the Login property is an object, but you are declaring it as a string. Also, you are creating a list and serializing that, which is leading to those square brackets ([, ]) around your JSON. Square brackets mark arrays or enumerations, whereas in your sample JSON you are just looking for an object.

One last tip, for classes that are used for serializing, you don't have to use properties. You can just declare your variables as public variables. The only time you need to use properties is if you need to modify or *do something* with its contents when it's being set or read. e.g., formatting a string when it's being set, or calculating a response when the variable is being retrieved (you can put code in the GET and SET methods to make them act like a function).

Something to note with serializing and deserializing, you can nest classes. When serialized they will be converted to JSON objects using the same object layout and variable name. So you can try something like this:

(UPDATED CODE)

```
Public Sub CreateJson()
    'Create Wrapper Object
    Dim Load As New fgtload

    Load.Login = New fgtLoginData With { 'Create Login Data
        .Username = "XXX",
        .Password = "pwxXXxx",
        .BusID = 123456789,
        .BusRole = "Third Party",
        .PaymentTerms = "Prepaid"
    }

    Load.Details = New fgtDetailsData With { 'Create Details
        .ServiceClass = "STD",
        .TypeQuery = "QUOTE",
        .PickupDate = "20200221",
        .ProductCode = "DFQ"
    }

    Load.OriginLocation = New fgtLocationnData With { 'Create Origin
        .City = "Keyport",
        .State = "NJ",
        .PostalCode = 7735,
        .Country = "USA",
        .LocationType = "COMM"
    }

    Load.DestinationLocation = New fgtLocationnData With { 'Create Destination
        .City = "Beverly Hills",
        .State = "CA",
        .PostalCode = 90210,
        .Country = "USA",
        .LocationType = "COMM"
    }

    'Create Commodities

    Dim Commodity1 As New fgtCommodity With {
        .PackageLength = 48,
        .PackageWidth = 48,
        .PackageHeight = 48,
        .Weight = 1500,
        .HandlingUnits = 1,
        .PackageCode = "PLT"
    }

    'Add commodity to load

    Load.ListOfCommodities.commodity.Add(Commodity1)


    'Serialize wrapper object

    Dim Json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Load)
End Sub
Public Class fgtload 'Primary wrapper
    Public Login As New fgtLoginData
    Public Details As New fgtDetailsData
    Public OriginLocation As New fgtLocationnData
    Public DestinationLocation As New fgtLocationnData
    Public ListOfCommodities As New fgtCommodityWrapper
End Class
Public Class fgtLoginData 'Login Data
    Public Username As String
    Public Password As String
    Public BusID As String
    Public BusRole As String
    Public PaymentTerms As String
End Class
Public Class fgtDetailsData 'Details Data
    Public ServiceClass As String
    Public TypeQuery As String
    Public PickupDate As String
    Public ProductCode As String
End Class
Public Class fgtLocationnData 'Location data for both Origin and Destination
    Public City As String
    Public State As String
    Public PostalCode As String
    Public Country As String
    Public LocationType As String
End Class
Public Class fgtCommodityWrapper 'Commodity Data
    Public commodity As New List(Of fgtCommodity) ' Lists get serialized into arrays
End Class
Public Class fgtCommodity
    Public PackageLength As Double 'Doubles to allow floating-point numbers
    Public PackageWidth As Double
    Public PackageHeight As Double
    Public Weight As Double
    Public HandlingUnits As Integer
    Public PackageCode As String
End Class
```

This creates this response.
(UPDATED OUTPUT)

```
{
    "Login": {
        "Username": "XXX",
        "Password": "pwxXXxx",
        "BusID": "123456789",
        "BusRole": "Third Party",
        "PaymentTerms": "Prepaid"
    },
    "Details": {
        "ServiceClass": "STD",
        "TypeQuery": "QUOTE",
        "PickupDate": "20200221",
        "ProductCode": "DFQ"
    },
    "OriginLocation": {
        "City": "Keyport",
        "State": "NJ",
        "PostalCode": "7735",
        "Country": "USA",
        "LocationType": "COMM"
    },
    "DestinationLocation": {
        "City": "Beverly Hills",
        "State": "CA",
        "PostalCode": "90210",
        "Country": "USA",
        "LocationType": "COMM"
    },
    "ListOfCommodities": {
        "commodity": [
            {
                "PackageLength": 48.0,
                "PackageWidth": 48.0,
                "PackageHeight": 48.0,
                "Weight": 1500.0,
                "HandlingUnits": 1,
                "PackageCode": "PLT"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

(UPDATE NOTES):

In response to your comment, I have modified the code in my response to allow or your updated expected output.

Note also that if two JSON objects have the same structure (in this case originLocation and destinationLocation) you can use the same class.

Also, see at the Commodity Data there are square brackets, this marks a JSON array. Arrays/Lists/Enumerations in your code will be serialized into JSON arrays, even if they are of a class type. So in this code example, you can add as many commodities to ListOfCommodities.commodity as you want and they will be properly serialized into JSON.

Comment: Yes it helps emensly. Thank you very much for the time you took to answer and also explaining in detail.  I put a shortend JSON output in my example for sake of brevity.  
There's a total of 5 classes which I can construct.  I've tried adding a details class to the wrapper but it fails.  

I dont think there's enough characters to put the whole expected output in here.   


Public Class Details  ' 
  Public ServiceClass As String
  Public typeQuery As String
  Public pickupDate As Integer
  Public productCode As String
 End Class

Comment: Daniel, Again, Thank you very much. From the last 4 classes you added I saw I was going in the wrong direction.  I was trying to add them inside inside the fgtload class. As stated I'm kind of new at all of this.   I do appreciate the lessons, help and excellent code with explaination.   Again Thank you very much.  I'm not sure how or if I have to mark this as answer as the accepted. If this is one of those point assigning sites or what.  I'll look around and see if I can find out becasue this is the answer i was looking and hoping for :) . Thanks

Comment: While hovering over the top of the response, you should see a greyed out tick, click it and it will mark it as the accepted answer. This goes pretty much across all of stack overflow's other sites as well.

Comment: Shimmy  are you still around?

Comment: Yea I'm still here, what's up @dashley?

Comment: Ha  I solved my question I wanted to ask you :)  I was tweaking some items in the sample above and painted myself in a corner HA HA.  Got it fixed though.  Thanks :)